# Finding the closest values within mutil group

Tags: r, group-by

My data 1 is

| id1 | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 |
| 1 | 101 |
| 1 | 118 |
| 1 | 170 |
| 2 | 95 |
| 2 | 201 |
| 3 | 160 |
| 4 | 70 |

My data2 is

| id2 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 120 |
| 2 | 105 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |

how can i use group_by or mutate (dplyr) for create the outcome column from  data2$value2 ?
Outcome table like this

| id1 | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 100 |
| 1 | 101 | 100 |
| 1 | 118 | 100 |
| 1 | 170 | 120 |
| 2 | 95 | 105 |
| 2 | 201 | 200 |
| 3 | 160 | 300 |
| 4 | 70 | NA |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a `dplyr`-solution. But imho `data.table`'s rolling joins are best practice for tasks like this.

```
library(data.table)
data1 <- fread("id1     value1
1   98
1   101
1   118
1   170
2   95
2   201
3   160
4   70")
data2 <- fread("id2     value2
1   100
1   120
2   105
2   200
3   300")

# alternatively, use:
# setDT(data1); setDT(data2)

# perform rolling join to nearest value with same id
data1[, value2 := data2[data1, x.value2, on = .(id2 = id1, value2 = value1), roll = "nearest"]][]
#    id1 value1 value2
# 1:   1     98    100
# 2:   1    101    100
# 3:   1    118    120
# 4:   1    170    120
# 5:   2     95    105
# 6:   2    201    200
# 7:   3    160    300
# 8:   4     70     NA
```

Comment: It works perfect! but i've adapt your code in my other data and got error msg : `Error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").` What wrong?
My R Studio version  1.4.1106
data.table packgage version  1.14.3
R version 4.0.5

Comment: Is your data a data.table?

Comment: Ahh i forgot to setDT on my data, now it works well Thanks a lot.!
ps.I'm a beginner in data.frame packgage :) .